# jar conflicts version commons-configuration

Tags: java, maven, jar

I do not find how to solve the following issue :

I use commons-configuration 1.8 with dependency with Commons-Lang 2.6
I also use  Commons-Lang 3.1.

As a sidenote, I use maven 3.

Is my app forced to bundle both commons-lang or is there a way out ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @phloc has pointed out, you will need both the versions because, `commons-lang` has undergone major changes from `2.6` to `3.1`.

From the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/article3_0.html),

maven

```
groupId: commons-lang -> org.apache.commons
artifactId: commons-lang -> commons-lang3
```

java code

```
import org.apache.commons.lang -> import org.apache.commons.lang3
```

commons-configuration 1.8 continues to use commons-lang 2.6. Hence you need this version as well.

Since the package structure is different, you will have no issues with them co-existing.

Comment: I had noticed the different packages but found it weird to be forced to bundle both versions. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think you must bundle both versions of commons-lang.
As commons-lang3 comes with a new namespace it should not be a problem at runtime!